# Relative path called with HTTPServlet

Tags: java, http, url, servlets, web.xml

I am currently developing a servlet which returns a lot of data to a given ID.
It is called under the URL

> localhost:8080/RTC_W/api?id=123

and has no special path given in the source code.
My web.xml maps it as followed:

`<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>APICaller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

It is called by a welcome file, which looks like this (relevant part only) and offers a little box to type in the ID:

```
<body>
RTC W Front End

<form action="/api" method="get"> 
  Work Item ID:<br>
  <input type="text" name="id" value=""><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
```

as you can see, form action should call path /api where the servlet is located. The URL called is wrong though, it always calls

> localhost:8080/api?id=123

So the /RTC_W/ is missing. If I add it to  `<form action="RTC_W/api" method="get">`, this URL gets called:

> localhost:8080/RTC_W/RTC_W/api?id=123

So the path is called twice. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="api" method="get">
```

This is what you should use.

When a URL starts with `/` it is always an absolute URL, i.e. appended right after the `<hostname>:<port>`

If a url does not start with `/` it will get appended to the current URL.